# How to keep a panel attached to it's parent panel while the parent panel is expanded or collapsed

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I am new to swing. I am using JFD to build a panel so that whenever the panel window is expanded or collapsed the inner content should also stay attached to the panel and get expanded or collapsed accordingly.

I have been using JFormDesigner plugin on IntelliJ to do so. Please find the tree view of the panel on attached images.

My question is which property of which panel should I look into to do so?

Probably I am not able to give you whole details while asking this question but I'm open for all the questions.

Here's my code:

```
public class aa extends JPanel 
{
    public aa() 
    {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void createUIComponents() {
        // TODO: add custom component creation code here
    }

    private void initComponents() 
    {
        // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
        DefaultComponentFactory compFactory = DefaultComponentFactory.getInstance();
        mSplitPane1 = new JSplitPane();
        mPanel1 = new JPanel();
        mSeparator1 = compFactory.createSeparator("text");
        mLabel6 = new JLabel();
        mTextField6 = new JTextField();
        mLabel9 = new JLabel();
        mTextField9 = new JTextField();
        mCheckBox1 = new JCheckBox();
        mLabel7 = new JLabel();
        mTextField7 = new JTextField();
        mLabel10 = new JLabel();
        mTextField10 = new JTextField();
        mLabel8 = new JLabel();
        mTextField8 = new JTextField();
        mLabel11 = new JLabel();
        mTextField11 = new JTextField();

        //======== this ========
        setName("this");
        setLayout(new FormLayout(
            "default:grow",
            "fill:default:grow"));

        //======== mSplitPane1 ========
        {
            mSplitPane1.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
            mSplitPane1.setDividerLocation(230);
            mSplitPane1.setOpaque(false);
            mSplitPane1.setName("splitPane1");

            //======== mPanel1 ========
            {
                mPanel1.setName("panel1");
                mPanel1.setLayout(new FormLayout(
                    "100dlu, $lcgap, 20dlu, $lcgap, 90dlu, $lcgap, default, $lcgap, 136dlu, $lcgap, 26dlu, $lcgap, 107dlu, $lcgap, default, $lcgap, 40dlu",
                    "6*(default, $lgap), 14dlu"));

                //---- mSeparator1 ----
                mSeparator1.setName("separator1");
                mPanel1.add(mSeparator1, CC.xywh(1, 1, 17, 1));

                //---- mLabel6 ----
                mLabel6.setText("text");
                mLabel6.setName("label6");
                mPanel1.add(mLabel6, CC.xy(1, 5, CC.RIGHT, CC.DEFAULT));

                //---- mTextField6 ----
                mTextField6.setName("textField6");
                mPanel1.add(mTextField6, CC.xy(5, 5));

                //---- mLabel9 ----
                mLabel9.setText("text");
                mLabel9.setName("label9");
                mPanel1.add(mLabel9, CC.xy(9, 5, CC.RIGHT, CC.DEFAULT));

                //---- mTextField9 ----
                mTextField9.setName("textField9");
                mPanel1.add(mTextField9, CC.xy(13, 5));

                //---- mCheckBox1 ----
                mCheckBox1.setText("text");
                mCheckBox1.setName("checkBox1");
                mPanel1.add(mCheckBox1, CC.xy(17, 5, CC.RIGHT, CC.DEFAULT));

                //---- mLabel7 ----
                mLabel7.setText("text");
                mLabel7.setName("label7");
                mPanel1.add(mLabel7, CC.xy(1, 9, CC.RIGHT, CC.DEFAULT));

                //---- mTextField7 ----
                mTextField7.setName("textField7");
                mPanel1.add(mTextField7, CC.xy(5, 9));

                //---- mLabel10 ----
                mLabel10.setText("text");
                mLabel10.setName("label10");
                mPanel1.add(mLabel10, CC.xy(9, 9, CC.RIGHT, CC.DEFAULT));

                //---- mTextField10 ----
                mTextField10.setName("textField10");
                mPanel1.add(mTextField10, CC.xy(13, 9));

                //---- mLabel8 ----
                mLabel8.setText("text");
                mLabel8.setName("label8");
                mPanel1.add(mLabel8, CC.xy(1, 13, CC.RIGHT, CC.DEFAULT));

                //---- mTextField8 ----
                mTextField8.setName("textField8");
                mPanel1.add(mTextField8, CC.xy(5, 13));

                //---- mLabel11 ----
                mLabel11.setText("text");
                mLabel11.setName("label11");
                mPanel1.add(mLabel11, CC.xy(9, 13, CC.RIGHT, CC.DEFAULT));

                //---- mTextField11 ----
                mTextField11.setName("textField11");
                mPanel1.add(mTextField11, CC.xywh(13, 13, 5, 1));
            }
            mSplitPane1.setTopComponent(mPanel1);
        }
        add(mSplitPane1, CC.xy(1, 1));
        // JFormDesigner - End of component initialization  //GEN-END:initComponents
    }

    // JFormDesigner - Variables declaration - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private JSplitPane mSplitPane1;
    private JPanel mPanel1;
    private JComponent mSeparator1;
    private JLabel mLabel6;
    private JTextField mTextField6;
    private JLabel mLabel9;
    private JTextField mTextField9;
    private JCheckBox mCheckBox1;
    private JLabel mLabel7;
    private JTextField mTextField7;
    private JLabel mLabel10;
    private JTextField mTextField10;
    private JLabel mLabel8;
    private JTextField mTextField8;
    private JLabel mLabel11;
    private JTextField mTextField11;
    // JFormDesigner - End of variables declaration  //GEN-END:variables
}
```

[image: after expansion]

[image: before]

[image: tree view]

Comment: It really comes down the layout manager and the constraints used to add the panel to that layout. It has nothing to do with the IDE or the GUI designer.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it will helps you or not, because you have no [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) attached, but I would change your layout as following:

```
    setLayout(new FormLayout(
        "default:grow",
        "fill:default:grow"));
```

To:

```
    setLayout(new FormLayout(
        "fill:default:grow", // row must fill all its content
        "fill:default:grow"));
```

Also:

```
        // change "default" -> to "glue". this allows to make an empty growing column
        // if you want to make your fields growing, you should make them "fill:default:grow"
        mPanel1.setLayout(new FormLayout(
                "100dlu, $lcgap, 20dlu, $lcgap, 90dlu, $lcgap, default, $lcgap, 136dlu, $lcgap, 26dlu, $lcgap, 107dlu, $lcgap, default, $lcgap, 40dlu",
                "6*(default, $lgap), 14dlu"));
```

To:

```
        mPanel1.setLayout(new FormLayout(
                "100dlu, $lcgap, 20dlu, $lcgap, 90dlu, $lcgap, glue, $lcgap, 136dlu, $lcgap, 26dlu, $lcgap, 107dlu, $lcgap, default, $lcgap, 40dlu",
                "6*(default, $lgap), 14dlu"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your help is appreciated. I had to make below changes:

`mPanel1.setLayout(new FormLayout(
                    "100dlu, $lcgap, 20dlu, $lcgap, 90dlu, $lcgap, default, $lcgap, 136dlu, $lcgap, 26dlu, $lcgap, 107dlu, $lcgap, default, $lcgap, 40dlu, $lcgap, default:grow",
                    "6*(default, $lgap), 14dlu"));`

and 
`mPanel1.add(mSeparator1, CC.xywh(1, 1, 19, 1));`

Had to add a blank column at last and had to change the resize property to grow by 1.